# Module.ResolveMember behavior for generic classes

Tags: c#

I don't understand Module.ResolveMember behavior for members with generic parameters. According to documentation code below should work, but fooMember.DeclaringType is not parameterized with bool type for some reason.

```
class A<T> where T:new()
{
    T a;
    public void foo()
    {
        a = new T();
    }
}
class B:A<bool>
{ }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new B();
        var aType = test.GetType().BaseType;
        var token = aType.GetMember("foo").First().MetadataToken;
        var fooMember = aType.Module.ResolveMember(token, aType.GetGenericArguments(), null);
        Debug.Assert(aType == fooMember.DeclaringType);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: "it does not work" is hard analyse, can you please elaborate? What output do you expect? What output can you see? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: i expect assert to pass. i think "...but fooMember.DeclaringType is not parameterized with bool type for some reason." is clear enough

Comment: You are getting the metadata token of `foo`, but since `foo` is not a generic member you can not parameterize it. I assume the `ResolveMember` method just ignores the second argument in this case.

Comment: `foo` doesn't have generic parameters, but it has generic type arguments because it is declared in the generic type. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.module.resolvemember?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Module_ResolveMember_System_Int32_System_Type___System_Type___) clearly states that the second parameter should not be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `ResolveMethod(Int32, Type[], Type[])` expects methodref token, and for generic methods we have different methodrefs for different generic arguments. `ResolveMethod` should be used to get method based on compilation dependent information, not to resolve generic method info.